# Deleting duplicate records from table

Tags: mysql

I want to delete duplicate records from a mysql table. It is executing fine, but it is displaying "no rows affected"?

```
DELETE n1 
FROM dummyuser1  n1, dummyuser1 n2
WHERE  n1.id > n2.id and  n1.name = n2.name;
```

The above query is executing but it is displaying "no rows affected".

Comment: can you provide us your sample data

Comment: Please eleborate your situation

Comment: show your table structure and on which field basis you want to make your data unique.

Comment: @Maruthi Marripudi: If you want to remove duplicity in name column and want to keep lowest id then your query is fine...if you create a sqlfiddle then someone can check what is the issue...

Comment: Hi, i created dummyuser1 table in this table i made 2 rows replica with same id,name, salary columns but i dont want to see. eg: first row 1,maruthi,30000 and second row is 2, dummyname,20000 and first row and 2 row all coloumns  are repeating twice, i  dont want to be like that, i want both replica rows to be unique.......

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just add a unique index that will delete all duplicate rows like:

```
alter ignore table dummyuser  
add unique index idx_uk_dummyuser (name);
```

And it help you in the future avoid the duplicates in your table

Comment: Adding a unique index won't delete duplicate entries. It will *fail* if there are duplicates.

Comment: @EJP As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error.

Comment: @EJP And I found the similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3312066/4275342 / My table type is MyISAM  and its works

Comment: @EJP: As MegaTron is using alter ignore syntax, so it will automatically remove duplicate records and keep only first record and will create unique index. My +1 for the answer.